# Right way to handle permissions based component rendering in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, permissions, roles, react-context

My app renders components and layout based on user permissions. Permissions are created dynamically. (permissions are basically what are the modules and actions that a user can do.

e.g: The user can delete records, update records, can view settings tab, etc

Permission Keys are coming from the backend. when the user hit the login API.

1. Should I use context to pass through the component tree?
2. What if the page refreshes? Then I need to call the API again to get permissions? should I need to store it in the session/local but a user can update and change the data in session/local storage also it is not secure. What should I do?

Comment: First of all: you can never rely on client-side data. So everything that is sent by the server needs to be authorized, regardless of a component being shown or not. 1. yes 2. yes (if you store some flag in localstorage, changing it is pointless if the normally hidden and now visible component / page won't populate)

Comment: How have you managed to implement this. I am looking for a similar solution. Where I not only want the ui components to be shown based on permission but also tie up the apis along with them. eg. to hide delete user button and the permission will also be apply on the delete /user api.